# How can I get my Copy and Paste function to keep new line formatting?

Tags: javascript, html, copy, copy-paste, paste

I only need this to work on Google Chrome so there is no requirement for multi-browser compatible code.

This is the JS function I use to copy the text to clipboard.

```
 // Copy text to clip-board JS
  
  function copy(txt){
    var cb = document.getElementById("cb");
    cb.value = txt;
    cb.style.display='block';
    cb.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    cb.style.display='none';
  }

 var var1='download here: \n www.link-to-download.com';
```

Here is my HTML

```
  <button class="buttonClass" onclick="copy(softwareinstall)">Install software</button>
    <textarea id="cb" style="display: none"></textarea>
```

When I click the button, it will copy to clipboard, however when I paste the content into somewhere else for example notepad and outlook, the text is all on one line and the \n does nothing.

I would like for the string to be split onto 2 seperate lines.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: try using `\r\n` for linebreaks. `\n` is the unix way.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I have tried using \r\n and this has had no effect, I have \n working using a different method, so I don't think it's the \n which is causing it not to work.

Comment: Your code works fine when changing `var1` to `softwareinstall`

Comment: @MarkBaijens Apologies, i wrote that out wrong on here, the actual code is correct. Still cant get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an option, you could easily preserve you text content by using `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` instead of `document.execCommand()` as that does not copy from the DOM. Something like:

```js
const str = "Text \n on \n different lines";
navigator.clipboard.writeText(str).then(() =>
   console.log("copied")
);
```

Comment: Apologies i'm fairly new to javascript. Do you mind breaking down how this works for me please?

Comment: The `writeText()` simply copies whatever text that is passed in into the clipboard without having to store/retrieve it from the DOM. It is asynchronous and that's the reason for the `.then(() => console.log("copied"))` which is an optional function that would be called when copying is complete

Comment: That's great, ill try that and ill update here if I can get it working.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the input element doesn't support line breaks, so your \n gets lost. Try to use a textarea instead:

```js
// Copy text to clip-board JS
  
  function copy(txt){
    var cb = document.getElementById("cb");
    cb.value = txt;
    cb.style.display='block';
    cb.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    cb.style.display='none';
  }

 var var1='first line of text \n second line of text';
```

```html
<button onclick="copy(var1)">Copy Option 1</button>
<textarea id="cb" style="display: none"></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here, if I run what you did in that example it works fine. But I've implemented this into my code and it's not worked for me. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Please can you see my edit.

Comment: Because the code in my answer (and in your edited question) is working, it would be very helpful to know the rest of the websites code. Maybe you can create a minimal example that shows the issue?